# Email category missing

Tags: office-interop, outlook-addin, outlook-2013

i faced with following issue:

I'm sending email from Outlook 2013 and have some processing using addin express. During this processing i'm creating new email and setting up category on it

> string[] elems = userLogin.Split(new char[] {'\'});
>
> mailItem.Categories = elems[1] + " " + mailItem.Categories;

But when i receive it on Outlook 2013 i don't see any category on it ... It was work on Outlook 2007 but now it stop work. Maybe you have any ideas what can be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Categories (Keywords) is a MAPI specific property. When a message is converted to MIME, MAPI specific properties are lost. You can force Outlook to send in the TNEF format (the infamous winmail.dat file) by setting the special UseTnef property to true:

```
MailItem.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B", true)
```

Comment: Looks very promising but i tried it and still don't see category when receive email ...

Comment: Do you see that property set if you look at the message in the Sent Items folder using OutlookSpy (click IMessage)? - http://www.dimastr.com/outspy

Comment: Witch property set? i see my category inside property "PidNameKeywords"

Comment: That's the one that contains the categories. Do you see the UseTnef property that your code sets?

Comment: Yes i see it but for some reason it's "false" in "ItemSent" folder. But this property "true" in inbox folder. This is my code:                              MailItem mailForDepartment = (MailItem)originalMail.Copy(); senderController.ModifyMailCopyBeforeSending(originalMail, mailForDepartment, senderMailAddress, senderMailName); mailForDepartment.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8582000B", true); mailForDepartment.Send();

Comment: Try to call mailForDepartment.Save before setting the property and calling Save.

Comment: If you replace Send with Save and look at the saved message in the Drafts folder, is the property set correctly;y?

Comment: If i use Save instead of Send i see the correct properties in Draft folder. So looks like Outlook rewrite all changes before Send email ...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure a category exists on the target PC, take a look at the [How to: Enumerate and Add Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff424467.aspx) article in MSDN.

The [Categories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff860423.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property is a delimited string of category names that have been assigned to an Outlook item. This property uses the character specified in the value name, **sList**, under *HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International* in the Windows registry, as the delimiter for multiple categories. I don't think it is a whitespace...

```
string[] elems = userLogin.Split(new char[] {'\'}); 
mailItem.Categories = mailItem.Categories + ", "+ elems[1];
```

See [How to: Assign Categories to an Item](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff424469.aspx) for more information.